# Function trigger other function and ends before result

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm developing an API with Django Rest Framework for handling some subscriptions

I wanted do make the registration in 2 steps.

First, i would register user in my database, after that i want to register user to other service (email marketing, for example).

I have to do it in two steps because the registering of the user in external services may take some time (or the service can be unavailable at the time of request) and i don't want users to wait everything so they can go to other pages.

My idea is: After registering user into my database, i would `return http 200_ok` to the front-end so user can go to other pages, and in my backend i would use that data to try to register the user in external services as many times as needed (e.g: waiting if other services are unavailable).

But rest_framework only allows me to `return Response()` (i'm using class-based views), so i only can **return** `http 200_ok`, but if i **return** the function ends and my other functions (that will take more time to run) will end aswell.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

This could help solve your background tasks